# How do you have Arena show the second and third best move in analysis?

Tags: engines, arena

How do you have Arena show the second and third best moves in analysis?
I seem to be able to only see the evaluation for the engine's best move.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the analysis output window to be able to enable Multi-PV mode:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Stop the Engine
2. Open Configure page
3. Set MultiPV option equal to 3

[image: Open Configure page]
[image: Set MultiPV option eual to 3]